# Constantly look for file, when file exist, run command

Tags: vbscript, monitor

I need a vbscript that monitors a folder for a specific file, when file is found it needs to execute a command then delete that file but continue to monitor the folder again for the same file incase it needs to run again.

This...

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Do While 1>0
   If FSO.FileExists (file.txt) Then 
       FSO.DeleteFile (file.txt)
       CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "c:\windows\notepad.exe"
   End If
   WScript.Sleep 1000
Loop
```

Gave me an `"object required: file"` error.

update, this worked...

```
FileName = "c:\vbscript\cat.txt"
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Do
   If FSO.FileExists(FileName) Then 
       FSO.DeleteFile FileName
       CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "c:\windows\notepad.exe"
   End If
   WScript.Sleep 1000
Loop
```

Comment: -0.49 for using spurious () in `FSO.DeleteFile (file.txt)`, using `1>0` instead of `True` or a simple `Do .. Loop`, and not quoting the (obvious) string literal "file.txt".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create a script that infinitely loops, testing for file existence and if it does delete it.

```
FileName = "Path\To\FileName"
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Do
   If FSO.FileExists(FileName) Then 
       FSO.DeleteFile FileName
   End If
   WScript.Sleep 1000
Loop
```

Comment: @Meoiswa -0.49 for the disgusting `1>0`, and not showing that `FileName` is meant as a variable that must be initialized.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner Agreed, I wrote that on a pinch because I was getting kicked out of the classroom.

Comment: @Meoiswa - please remove the `Set` in the assignment (of a string, not an object) to `FileName`; and Window's path separator is "\".

Comment: Thanks, not really familiar with vbscript.

Comment: @Meoiswa +1 for concept/idea, implementation, and diligence,