# Backup a while with added timestamp and delete original in a loop

Tags: file-io, vbscript

The main part of the code does work when manually started, but not as needed when I used an external program to initiate, so I felt doing it AIO was better ..

When I added the few lines to delete the file after it is backed up and to loop (marked as pt1, pt2, pt3 in the code), I get the following syntax error:

```
Line:  66
Char  1
Syntax Error
800A03EA  MS VBscript compilation error
```

As reference these are the links where I checked and copied from:

[Constantly look for file, when file exist, run command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16341402/constantly-look-for-file-when-file-exist-run-command)

http://www.devhut.net/2013/11/15/vbscript-backup-a-file-and-add-a-date-time-stamp/

```
'--------------------------------------START OF ADDED CODE pt1'
Do
'---------------------------------END OF ADDED CODE pt1'   

Dim objFSO 

Dim sSourceFolder 

Dim sDestFolder 

Dim sDBFile 

Dim sDateTimeStamp 

Const OVER_WRITE_FILES = True   


Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

sSourceFolder = "C:\Program Files\N H P"

sBackupFolder = "C:\Program Files\N H P\ArchiveData"

sDBFile = "N-H-P" 

sDBFileExt = "csv" 

sDateTimeStamp = cStr(Year(now())) & _ 
        Pad(cStr(Month(now())),2) & _ 
        Pad(cStr(Day(now())),2) & _ 
        Pad(cStr(Hour(now())),2) & _ 
        Pad(cStr(Minute(now())),2)  


'If the backup folder doesn't exist, create it. 

If Not objFSO.FolderExists(sBackupFolder) Then 

objFSO.CreateFolder(sBackupFolder) 

End If   


'Copy the file as long as the file can be found 

If objFSO.FileExists(sSourceFolder & "\" & sDBFile & "." & sDBFileExt) Then 
    objFSO.CopyFile sSourceFolder & "\" & sDBFile & "." & sDBFileExt,_ 
        sBackupFolder & "\" & sDBFile & "_" & sDateTimeStamp & "." & sDBFileExt,_ 
        OVER_WRITE_FILES 
End if   


Set objFSO = Nothing     


Function Pad(CStr2Pad, ReqStrLen) 

Dim Num2Pad   


Pad = CStr2Pad 

If len(CStr2Pad) < ReqStrLen Then 

Num2Pad = String((ReqStrlen - Len(CStr2Pad)), "0") 

Pad = Num2Pad & CStr2Pad 

End If 


'-------------------------------------------START OF ADDED CODE pt2'
'Delete the file as long as the file can be found 

If objFSO.FileExists(sSourceFolder & "\" & sDBFile & "." & sDBFileExt) Then 
    objFSO.DeleteFile sSourceFolder & "\" & sDBFile & "." & sDBFileExt,_ 
        OVER_WRITE_FILES 
End if   

'-------------------------------------END OF ADDED CODE pt2'

Set objFSO = Nothing 

End Function

'--------------------------------START OF ADDED CODE pt3'

   WScript.Sleep 50000

Loop

 '------------------------------------START OF ADDED CODE pt3'
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that within your Do Loop. You try to declare a new function within the loop.  I'd really recommend formatting your code a bit more, it makes it easier to find mistakes.  Also a notepad editor that has visual brace matching (Notepad2, Notepad++, etc) help.  Here's your code formatted and fixed, though I didn't test the actual copying, deleting.

```
Dim objFSO
Dim sSourceFolder, sDestFolder, sDBFile, sDateTimeStamp 

Const OVER_WRITE_FILES = True   

Do
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

    sSourceFolder = "C:\Program Files\N H P"
    sBackupFolder = "C:\Program Files\N H P\ArchiveData"
    sDBFile = "N-H-P" 
    sDBFileExt = "csv" 

    sDateTimeStamp = cStr(Year(now())) & _ 
            Pad(cStr(Month(now())),2) & _ 
            Pad(cStr(Day(now())),2) & _ 
            Pad(cStr(Hour(now())),2) & _ 
            Pad(cStr(Minute(now())),2)

    'If the backup folder doesn't exist, create it. 
    If Not objFSO.FolderExists(sBackupFolder) Then
        objFSO.CreateFolder(sBackupFolder)
    End If   


    'Copy the file as long as the file can be found 
    If objFSO.FileExists(sSourceFolder & "\" & sDBFile & "." & sDBFileExt) Then 
        objFSO.CopyFile sSourceFolder & "\" & sDBFile & "." & sDBFileExt,_ 
            sBackupFolder & "\" & sDBFile & "_" & sDateTimeStamp & "." & sDBFileExt,_ 
            OVER_WRITE_FILES 
    End If   

    'Delete the file as long as the file can be found 

    If objFSO.FileExists(sSourceFolder & "\" & sDBFile & "." & sDBFileExt) Then 
        objFSO.DeleteFile sSourceFolder & "\" & sDBFile & "." & sDBFileExt,_ 
            OVER_WRITE_FILES 
    End if

    Set objFSO = Nothing   
    WScript.Sleep 50000
Loop

Function Pad(CStr2Pad, ReqStrLen)
    Dim Num2Pad   

    Pad = CStr2Pad
    If len(CStr2Pad) < ReqStrLen Then
        Num2Pad = String((ReqStrlen - Len(CStr2Pad)), "0") 
        Pad = Num2Pad & CStr2Pad 
    End If
End Function
```